# I am trying to create a symmetric matrix from the output I got in python without using the numpy and additional library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the matrix for the multiple sequence alignment and this is my score matrix which I got by running the alignment algorithm.
My matrix:

```
[
  [0, 24, -5, 3, -3, -5], 
  [0, -4, 8, 1, 1], 
  [0, 13, 1, 2], 
  [0, -2, 5], 
  [0, 4], 
  [0]
]
```

Matrix I want to build:

```
[
  [0, 24, -5, 3, -3, -5], 
  [24, 0, -4, 8, 1, 1], 
  [-5, -4, 0, 13, 1, 2], 
  [3, 8, 13, 0, -2, 5], 
  [-3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
  [-5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0]
]
```

I am trying to create a symmetric matrix from the output I got in python without using NumPy and additional library. I have tried to implement using NumPy but I want to implement without using NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
upper = [[0, 24, -5, 3, -3, -5], [0, -4, 8, 1, 1], [0, 13, 1, 2], [0, -2, 5], [0, 4], [0]]

n = len(upper) # 6: num of rows and cols (assuming square)

output = []
for i in range(n): # iterate over rows
    row = [(upper[i][j - i] if j >= i else output[j][i]) for j in range(n)]
    output.append(row)

print(output)
# [[0, 24, -5, 3, -3, -5], [24, 0, -4, 8, 1, 1], [-5, -4, 0, 13, 1, 2], [3, 8, 13, 0, -2, 5], [-3, 1, 1, -2, 0, 4], [-5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck here for so long. Finally able to go ahead